# Python Multiprocessing with PyWin32 for faster bulk email processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, win32com

I have a task in which I need to process approximately 20,000 emails from a .pst file which is saved on my machine - ultimately these will be moved via an API, however - I need to process each of the emails and put their data into a suitably formatted POST request. Ideally I would like to speed up this processes by utilising Python's multiprocessing module.

My understanding of the win32com module was that once you are looking at the Items object for emails you can iterate over each email - I have done this before with For loops etc. However when I introduce it as the iterable in the map() function, the program just appears to do nothing.

It would be really helpful if someone could shed some light on how to use multiprocessing to apply a map function to a set of outlook emails from the win32com module.

Thanks in advance

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import win32com.client

def f(x):
    print(x.Subject)

    ## More processing logic - producing a dict with data in the right format ##

    return processed_email

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    OutlookDataIndex = 4 # folder of interest

    folder = mapi.Folders.Item(OutlookDataIndex).Folders["Emails"]

    emails = folder.Items

    results = []

    with Pool(5) as p:
        results = (p.map(f, emails))
```

Comment: If you were to iterate `folder.Items` and print each item, what would the results be?

Answer (score 0):

After some time looking at it I was able to figure out a workaround -

Whilst folder.Items is iterable, the script actually is interacting with the outlook application when it iterates through the items. For this reason, having multiple cpus interacting with the same instance of the win32com.client wasn't going to work.

In order for this to work, I sized the folder using `num_emails = len(folder.Items)` and then instantiated a new win32com.client for each core, using `range(num_emails)` as the iterable in the `map()` function. The email item can then be indexed by using the index inside the iteration.

It does feel a bit long winded to re-instantiate the client, and could be made more reliable by passing the folder index etc. to the function as well - however for the purposes of this task it has worked

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import win32com.client

def f(x):

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    # Locate the "Outlook Data File/ToSend" folder

    OutlookDataIndex = 4

    folder = mapi.Folders.Item(OutlookDataIndex).Folders["Test Set"]

    emails = folder.Items

    email = emails[x]

    ## More processing logic - producing a dict with data in the right format ##

    return processed_email

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    except NotImplementedError:
        cpus = 2

    print(cpus)

    start_time = time.time()
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    # Locate the "Outlook Data File/ToSend" folder

    OutlookDataIndex = 4

    folder = mapi.Folders.Item(OutlookDataIndex).Folders["Test Set"]

    emails = folder.Items

    sum_emails = len(emails)

    results = []

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)

    results = pool.map(f, range(sum_emails))

    print(results)
```